# How do I install multiple setups in a single installation?

Tags: c#, installation

I have created a piece of software to download data from finger-scanners and write them to a database. The drivers of them should be installed first, so the driver setups should be installed while he installs the software. I don't know how to do it. It is written in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a setup for your app using Visual Studio Setup Projects. It helps you to run external exe s or msi s when your setup runs.

Go to File -> New -> Project -> Other Project types -> Setup and Deployment to create a setup project as you prefer. Then you may use `Custom actions` to add the feature you requrire. (The 3rd and 4th links below shows about custom actions).

Refer to:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Win_App_Setup_Project.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/ExtendVSSetupProject.aspx

http://devdump.wordpress.com/2009/01/17/setup-project-custom-actions/

http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/visual-studio-setup---projects-and-custom-actions/

Also you may create a script based installer for your app, which will let you create an installer with with high customizability and features.

Refer to

[Main Page - NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)

[Embedding other installers - NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Embedding_other_installers)

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

You can't run an MSI based install from a Visual Studio custom action. MSI doesn't permit that kind of recursive install (because it's a transaction, and because it tries to use system restore points per install etc). That's part of the reason why other prerequisites are installed by the setup.exe program. The bootstrap manifest generator can be used to generate custom prerequisites (first topic in this forum).
From:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/dfb5de84-a0f0-4639-958e-8cbf4cba6e90/setup-deployment-project-cannot-launch-another-installation?forum=winformssetup